# How to refresh record page when related objects are created

Tags: lightning, page-layout

When a user adds a related object on a contact you can see the newly added record instantly. However in a trigger we add another related object to the contact (an Opportunity) and to see this newly added related record in the related list, the user has to refresh the page.

The users don't understand the record has been created automatically since it is not displayed in the interface without a page refresh which leads to them creating it by themselves, thus resulting in a duplicate.

Any ideas how to update the record page everytime a related object is added? I tried with a hidden aura component to look for record changes but doesn't work:

```
<aura:component description="refreshViewOnChange" implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="record" type="Contact"
                description="The record object to be displayed"/>
<aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Contact"
                description="A simplified view record object to be displayed"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"
                description="An error message bound to force:recordData"/>
<force:recordData aura:id="record"
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                  targetRecord="{!v.record}"
                  targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
                  mode="VIEW"
                  recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdated}"/>
```

along with controller to react for recordUpdated:

```
recordUpdated: function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log("recordUpdated2");
    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
},
```